# Is there a way to list permissions for a given module?

Tags: drush

Using Drush 9, I am trying to automate the creation of a role and I need to assign permissions to it. I see that I can use `drush role-add-perm` to do the assignment itself, but I can't find a command to actually give me the permissions supplied by the enabled modules.

It looks like this was doable in older versions of Drush, but I'm not sure Drush 9 has equivalent commands.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You could use `drush cim` and create a yml for your role like for example

```
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies: {  }
id: myrole
label: 'My super Role'
weight: 1
is_admin: false
permissions: 
  - 'whatever 1'
  - 'whatever 2'
```

And if you don't know what perms your module brings, you could use that simple eval code with drush:

```
drush php-eval '$p = Drupal::service("user.permissions")->getPermissions(); foreach ($p as $k => $x) print $k." : ".$x["provider"]."\n";'
```

Comment: And you grep the possible permissions of moduleX from modules/custom/moduleX/moduleX.permissions.yml

Comment: This will be nice to be provided out-the-box by Drush, the same as it's done with roles.